# « Chaussée » et accent aigu

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques

D'après mon expérience et les cours du français je pensais que après deux consonnes identiques ce n'est pas possible la présence d'un **e** accentué.

Je viens de réaliser que *chaussée* comporte un tel *e* accentué.

Est-ce une exception (si oui, il existe d'autres) ou ma « règle empirique » était incorrecte ?

Comment: La règle empirique est erronée, car la crème est fouettée.

Comment: Merci bien. Je ne sais pas d'où ais-je obtenu cette idée...Je dois réexaminer les règles dans un bon ouvrage.

Comment: Peut-être parce que **devant** deux consonnes, l'accent est plus rare ..

Comment: Merci encore. Maintenant je viens réalisé que j'ai confondu les cas (devant et derrière; voici par exemple un e accentué avant deux lettres:-)!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La règle concerne la présence d'accents sur un **e** placé **avant** une consonne double, pas après !

Dans ce cas, il est exact que l'on ne met jamais d'accent car il est implicite.

Une explication intéressante à propos de cette absence d'accent: *[Comprendre l'orthographe du français](http://www.cilf.fr/livre-Comprendre_l_orthographe_du_fran%C3%A7ais-213-1-1-0-1.html)*, Hubert JOLY :

> Avant le XVIIIe siècle et la mise en œuvre de l'accent grave, le redoublement de la consonne était le moyen graphique utilisé pour transcrire le son /e ouvert/ devant une consonne. Depuis que l'usage de l'accent grave a été introduit dans nos habitudes d'écriture (1740), il y a concurrence entre le système ancien et le système récent, d'où des graphies comme violet > violette (ancien système) et discret > discrète (nouveau système)

Comment: Je vous remercie vivement pour la réponse et le site. C'est super !

Answer (score 1):

Quoique dans quelques cas de conjugaison on redouble une consonne lorsque la conjugaison se termine par un e caduc...

- **Appeler** : j’appe**ll**e — je suis appe**l**é
- **Épeler** : j’épe**ll**e — j’ai épe**l**é

...c’est davantage l’exception que la règle. Les verbes dont l’infinitif ne comporte qu’une consonne final avant la terminaison de l’infinitif n’en ont habituellement qu’une même lorsqu’une conjugaison se termine par un e caduc :

- **Embêter** : j’embê**t**e — je suis embê**t**é
- **Peler** : je pè**l**e — j’ai pe**l**é
- **Traîner** : je traî**n**e — j’ai traî**n**é

Et ceux qui possèdent une consonne doublée à l’infinitif la préservent dans toutes leurs conjugaisons :

- **Coller** : je suis co**ll**é
- **Emballer** : je suis emba**ll**é
- **Enferrer** : je suis enfe**rr**é

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Du coup, j'ai confondu la règle.